# html response data is converted to Json object in ibm mobile first adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

i am expecting text/html as response from ibm mobile first adapter,but it is giving json object from response.As described in ibm dev adapter gives only json object as response.so How can i convert response json to actual html.

Comment: What kind of adapter are you using? Can you provide a code snippet of that adapter? Can you also provide the message that is returned?

Comment: i am using javascript adapter and  expected output is html ,but getting Json form of html                                                                      Code:   var input = {
      method : 'post',
      returnedContentType : 'text/html',
      path : 'url',
      headers:{
       
       'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
       'accepts': 'text/html',
         
      },
      body:{
       content: data,
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       
      }
  };
 
  var response = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
   WL.Logger.error(response);

Answer (score 0):

Check this page from the documentation:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_java_server_side_api.html

If you use Java adapters this is possible via updating the @Produces annotation.

```
@Context
AdapterSecurityContext securityContext;

@OAuthSecurity(scope = "userLogin")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String sayHello() {
   AuthenticatedUser user = securityContext.getAuthenticatedUser();
   return "Hello " + user.getDisplayName();
}
```

If you use the javascript adapter, I believe you will have to pack the html text into in a encoded response into a property encoded into your JSON Result.

Reference to docs:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WLResourceRequest.html

Regards,